# How to get list of updated columns from within a trigger in IBM Db2 9.7?

Tags: triggers, db2

I am using DB2 9.7 enterprise edition on Windows 7. I have created a trigger and now I need to know which columns have been updated, from within the trigger. In MS SQL 2008 there is a function called "COLUMNS_UPDATED()" that gives you just that. However, after a lot of searching I cannot find an equivalent function for DB2. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 does not have a comparable function like this. Compare OLD and NEW values in triggers.